# Почему не видны границы строк в таблице и границы таблицы?

Tags: html, css

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>gfgf</td></tr>
  <tr><td>gfgf</td></tr>
  <tr><td>gfgf</td></tr>
  <tr><td>gfgf</td></tr>
</table>
```

нужно внутри строки вставить ячейку `<td>` внутри каждой строки она должна быть

Comment: Т.е. необходимо содержимое? Спасибо.

Comment: а как же? зачем тогда таблица, если она пустая?) хотя можно и без содержимого запустить, просто уберите из ячейки td текст и все, рамка останется